# how do I delete .jar files in the JRE System Library?

Tags: java, eclipse

My homework assignment for my class gave me a lot of .java files to import, I was fiddling with eclipse trying to find a way to import them in the package (I did not realize I could just drag and drop..), but instead I imported them in the JRE System library folder, where I can no longer remove them.

I understand the mistake that I made, however I cannot find a way to remove these files from JRE 1.7.

I re-installed eclipse, and even deleted the JRE7 folder and reinstalled JRE. But the files are still here.

[image: JRE System Library]

Comment: in the image, which files do you want to delete? The JARs that you have highlighted looks legit JRE JARs. Or did you import your own classes in those JARs? If you want to change those JARs, you have to update that on the filesystem - not in Eclipse. But I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I accidentally imported those JAR files...

Comment: you mean imported under `JRE System Library` in Eclipse?

Comment: you can't remove those libraries shown in the picture they are belongs to JRE

Answer (score 4):

Go to **Window -> Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs -> select the jre -> edit -> click on the jar to remove -> remove on the right menu.**

Answer (score 0):

Easier way would be

> File->new java project->configure jre(blue text)->(it will show the
>   installed jres and you can remove any which you dont want)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on "Exercise19" project => Build Path => Configure build path
Goto to "libraries" tab. and remove this system library and click ok.
Above step may give some complication errors in your project.

Then try adding a new library (the correct one) via
Eclipse "Window => Preferences => Java => Installed JREs"

Then go back to project => Build Path => Configure build path ("libraries" tab)
and "Add library" => "JRE System Library", click ok.

it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Q. How to remove JRE System Library from project?**

**Ans**: Go to project then

> > **Right click** on project---> **Build Path**-->**Configure build path**
>
> Now there are 4 tabs **Source, Projects, Libraries, Order and Export**
>
> Go to
>
> > **Libraries tab** --> **click on JRE System Library** --> Then **Remove** it.

---

**Q. How to add JRE System Library to project?**

**Ans**: Go to project then

> > **Right click** on project---> **Build Path**-->**Configure build path**
>
> Now there are 4 tabs **Source, Projects, Libraries, Order and Export**
>
> Go to
>
> > **Libraries tab** --> Click on **Add Library** (shown at the right side)
> >     --> select **JRE System Library** --> **Next**-->**click  Alternate JRE --> select Installed JRE--> Finish --> Apply--> OK.**